# Permission issues while setting up cakephp

Tags: permissions, opensuse, apache-httpd

I am pretty new to linux and trying to setup cakephp on opensuse 12.1.
I did as told on the cakephp website(blog tutorial) and most probably encountering some permission issues.
I slapped the cakephp folder in /srv/www/htdocs and then tried to access it using localhost/cakephp where it says

```
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
```

But as i check for permissions I get

```
Suse:/srv # ls -lR shows sankalp as owner for all the files down the tree.

sankalp@Suse:/srv/www/htdocs> whoami
sankalp
sankalp@Suse:/srv/www/htdocs> ls -l
total 108
drwxrwxrwx  6 sankalp users  4096 Jun 27 12:44 cakephp
-rw-r--r--  1 sankalp users 73728 Jul  6 10:41 das
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sankalp  root    302 Mar 13  2006 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sankalp  root     26 Jun 28 19:04 whoami.php
```

Neither can I access whoami.php while favicon.ico gets displayed in the browser.What am I doing wrong here when I have given 777 to the user.

Comment: What webserver are you using and who is it running as?

Comment: I am using apache and as for 'who you are running it as?' isn't it the same as the user account am currently logged on as.(output of whoami)?

Comment: Depends how you started it - but generally it runs as `www-data`.

Comment: Please read [For security reasons why should /var/www not have chmod 777](http://askubuntu.com/q/20105) and [Why is it so important to remove 777 permissions?](http://serverfault.com/q/265205) I don't know if setting the permissions to 777 caused the problem (do try setting them to a reasonable value, i.e. 755 for executables and directories and 644 for other files), but it is a bad idea even anyway.